# Why this is an empirical relation?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

As a high school student I am not sure why this following formula which is used as a relation between *mean*, *median* and  *mode*   found to hold for [*unimodal distribution*](https://g.co/kgs/EBDtbh), is called **empirical**:$$ mean-mode=3(mean-median)$$ is there really no mathematical proof? My text book says that this is completely based on symmetry. Can some one help me to clarify this? Is there any existing proof in higher classes? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:Later I found this in [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3787/302733) but that's not quite accessible to me I will be happy if I get a simpler version or at least an intuitive understanding.

Comment: Not that I know the answer (and there most definitely is a proof somewhere out there), but It may intuitively help to rewrite the formula into $mean=\frac{1}{2}(median-mode)$

Comment: Do you have a source for this, so we can give it some context? It's certainly not true of all distributions. It implies the mean won't be in between the median & mode, but actually all 6 orders can be obtained with ingenuity. But perhaps some empirically useful distribution satisfies it (beside one for which the mean, median & mode are all equal - such as a Normal distribution - thus making it trivial).

Comment: @Graviton I don't think you rearranged that right.